# How can i convert a big bmp to a png?

Tags: java, android, bitmap, png, out-of-memory

I'm trying to convert a very big bmp file to a png.

I'm writing an app to make fractal image and I want to make a very high resolution image (like ultrahd).

I'll save bitmap pixel image directly into file with RandomAccessFile, so I will not allocate any Bitmap object into memory. The problem will be to convert the temporany bitmap to a png.

I found BitmapRegionDecoder but it is not usefull for my problem.

It is not easy to convert an image without a full data load. :(

I think a good solution could be a method look like: convertToPng(InputStream bitmapData, OutputStream pngStream).

**My question is, how can i convert a very big bitmap to a png without have an OutOfMemoryException?**

Comment: Aaand the question is...?

Comment: you are lucky because BMP data structure is not compressed and each pixel has its own int data, so as you mentioned, first open the stream, you need to skip the header data(I don't know what is the iso! search the structure). you need to read the pixel data as buffer, read->process->save and finally put all them together. have you tried something?! btw, good question +1

Comment: Yes, it is easy to read and write bitmap, i don't know how to encode it to a png using a buffer or byte stream :(

Comment: yes it is! i have not try it yet but documentation is clear. Thank you! ♥

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the [PNGJ](https://code.google.com/p/pngj/) library (disclaimer: I'm the author) which allows to read/write PNG images line by line.

Comment: the library is amazing. I build this app with your library. I can render 4K fractal image without any problem! Thank you! https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=it.cronosoft.thefract

Comment: You're welcome. To be included in https://code.google.com/p/pngj/wiki/Users you can drop a comment there.